# Error: Unknown column 'table1.table2PrimaryKey in field list in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

The schema is pre-existing and TeamGame and TeamPool are two models with hasMany association. As far as I understand, Sequelize has been unable to understand the foreign Key (PoolID) in csc_Game table and trying to find some column "cscPoolPoolID (table2PrimaryKey)"

How can I fix this issue? Is there any documentation on how Sequelize comprehends various columns and associations in pre-existing schema?

```
const TeamGame = db.define(
  'csc_Game',
  {
    GameID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: 'csc_Game',
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

export default TeamGame;
```

```
const TeamPool = db.define(
  'csc_Pool',
  {
    PoolID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: 'csc_Pool',
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

export default TeamPool;
```

```
Association: 
TeamPool.hasMany(TeamGame, {
  foreignKey: 'PoolID',
});
TeamGame.belongsTo(TeamPool);
```

The error Shown is:
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
errno: 1054,
sqlState: '42S22',
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'csc_Games.cscPoolPoolID' in 'field list'",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always indicate the same `foreignKey` option in both paired associations:

```js
TeamPool.hasMany(TeamGame, {
  foreignKey: 'PoolID',
});
TeamGame.belongsTo(TeamPool, {
  foreignKey: 'PoolID',
});
```